# How to make pylint recognize variable via astroid

Tags: python, django, pylint

I'm trying to "teach" pylint to recognize member function, my scenario can be simplified to the following:

Main module: a.py

```
from plugins import plu

class FooClass(object):
    def bar(self):
        self.plu.foo("asdasd")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = FooClass()
    for plugin_name, plugin in plu.plugins.items():
       setattr(a, plugin_name, plugin())
 a.bar()
```

Plugins folder file plu.py:

```
plugins = {}
class Plugin(object):
   def foo(self, arg):
       print("bar %s" % arg)

plugins['plu'] = Plugin
```

The idea that plugins register themselves and some other method "introduces" them on the `FooClass` object.

Output of the a.py is:

```
bar asdasd
```

(as expected)

Running `pylint -E a.py` yields the following error:

```
pylint  -E a.py 
************* Module a
E:  5, 8: Instance of 'FooClass' has no 'plu' member (no-member)
```

I had tried to write the following pylint-plugin:

```
import astroid
from astroid import nodes


def transform_test_class(mod):
   if mod.name != 'a':
       return
   foo_cls = mod.lookup('FooClass')[1]
   plugin_cls_def =   astroid.MANAGER.ast_from_module_name('plugins.plu')
   foo_cls[0].locals['plu'] = plugin_cls_def.lookup('Plugin')[1]


def register(linter):
   astroid.MANAGER.register_transform(nodes.Module,    transform_test_class)
```

Output of running `pylint --load-plugins=$(pwd)/pylint-plugin -E a.py` is:

```
************* Module a
E:  5, 8: No value for argument 'arg' in unbound method call (no-value-for-parameter)
```

From the error I suspect that somehow I introduce the property incorrectly, as pylint thinks that method `foo` is unbounded, but it is indeed bounded. I need to find a way to tell pylint that `foo_cls[0].locals['plu']` is actually an instance of class `Plugin` and not the class itself.  Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the plugin class when adding it to the locals of the FooClass. So replace this line `foo_cls[0].locals['plu'] = plugin_cls_def.lookup('Plugin')[1]` with `foo_cls[0].locals['plu'] = [cls.instantiate_class() for cls in plugin_cls_def.lookup('Plugin')[1]]`